# how to query daily cost of specific product in bigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

I exported billing to bigquery and I want to get the translations total cost in specific date from bigQuery monthly or specific date. like April 1, 2019.

google docs sample query get monthly.

```
SELECT
  invoice.month,
  SUM(cost)
    + SUM(IFNULL((SELECT SUM(c.amount)
                  FROM UNNEST(credits) c), 0))
    AS total,
  (SUM(CAST(cost * 1000000 AS int64))
    + SUM(IFNULL((SELECT SUM(CAST(c.amount * 1000000 as int64))
                  FROM UNNEST(credits) c), 0))) / 1000000
    AS total_exact
FROM `project.dataset.gcp_billing_export_v1_XXXXXX_XXXXXX_XXXXXX`
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1 ASC
;
```

but I created my query this way:

```
$myVariable=
    "SELECT 
          COUNT(*) total_times,
          SUM(cost) total_cost
    FROM 
          `project.dataset.gcp_billing_export_v1_XXXXXX_XXXXXX_XXXXXX`
    WHERE 
          service.description = 'Translate' AND (usage_end_time >= timestamp('2019-04-04 00:00:00') AND usage_end_time <= timestamp('2019-04-04 23:59:59'))";
```

I want to get the total cost of the current day and the total cost from the first day of the month to the current day.

```
sample:
1. 2019/04/04: 4223.05 - (882 Times)
2. 2019/04/Total: 16505.43 - (3882 Times)
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. This is not a coding service website. Show us, what you have done so far in a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example and you'll get help
https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 2):

You can further add details to your working query:

```
SELECT
  service.description,
  timestamp_trunc(usage_start_time,DAY) as time_fragment,
  ROUND(SUM(cost)
    + SUM(IFNULL((SELECT SUM(c.amount)
                  FROM UNNEST(credits) c), 0)),3)
    AS total,
  round((SUM(CAST(cost * 1000000 AS int64))
    + SUM(IFNULL((SELECT SUM(CAST(c.amount * 1000000 as int64))
                  FROM UNNEST(credits) c), 0))) / 1000000,3)
    AS total_exact
FROM `project.dataset.gcp_billing_export_v1_XXXXXX_XXXXXX_XXXXXX`
WHERE service.description='Translate'
GROUP BY 1,2
ORDER BY 2 desc;
```

which displays:

[image]

you can further to into HOURly granularity if you edit line 3.

Comment: sorry, I updated my question and added details, please see thanks